# How do I properly create a Library in Java?

Tags: java, lib

I have just created a library that will store and add elements into Hashmap.
I have generated a jar file , and placed it  into the Desktop. How can i use my library and work with it , i have already placed it into library folder , but what next, how can i work with it ?
any help pls
[Here is my library that i wan to use it i my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqNxN.png)

```
//here is my Library code

public class Main {
    public Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> boombom = new HashMap();
        addElements1(boombom, 1, "XML serv.");
        printElements(boombom);
    }

    private static void printElements(Map<Integer, String> boombom) {
        System.out.println(boombom);
    }

    private static void addElements1(Map<Integer, String> boombom, int i, String s) {
        boombom.put(i, s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `import myLibrary;`, to the top of your project, I believe

Comment: Not working , it is not seeing my library(

Comment: In any case, why is  your library class named  Main, and has a main(string[] args) function? That is unnecessary. Second.

Comment: There's lots of things potentially wrong: I'm not quite sure if your mylibrary.jar actually contains the `class` files (which would be correct) or just the `.java` files, because it also contains project-related files that should *not* be in a jar file (the `.iml`). Additionally it seems that both your library *and* your code that tries to use the library have a class called `Main` in the unnamed package. That's not going to work! Only one of those will be loaded if they are both on the classpath. Generally speaking as soon as your code spans more than one file your code should be in packages.

Comment: A library is essentially an  extension to your codebase. Any classes that you add to it would be accessible in the rest of the project, where it was imported.

Simply, Create your class, as you normally would in your main file, then just copy it over to your library file. Name the class the same as the file, to simplify matters. No need to overcomplicate things at this juncture in your learning path.

Comment: @RoeyMichaeli
could you please show me how to do a simple library of what i am doing. Cause i made it from tutorials from youtube (

Comment: Just a second..

Comment: @JoachimSauer but how can i make it without main method , could you please show me

Comment: @ProgramCOder: a library almost never has a main method (that would only make sense when it has a dual-purpose of also being a stand-alone executable). And the very first step is to make sure that your class names are different in your library and where you use it and also to put every class into some package.

Comment: I do not know who you are listening to, I would suggest you learn from this gentleman.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WYJLkd3R9M&list=PLkeaG1zpPTHiMjczpmZ6ALd46VjjiQJ_8
I trust he will guide you properly. If you followed the course, and you got this, Change your course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A library is essentially an extension to your codebase. Any classes that you add to it would be accessible in the rest of the project, where it was imported.

Simply, Create your class, as you normally would in your main file, then just copy it over to your library file. Name the class the same as the file, to simplify matters.

No need to overcomplicate things at this juncture in your learning path. I believe this should work. I have not tested this, however the fundamentals are correct.

This is not a static library, thus, in order to be used, it must be instantiated, like so:

```
MyLibrary myLibrary = new MyLibrary();
```

Then, since the functions inside the class are public, you would be able to call them like this:

```
myLibrary.addElements1(1, "ESPS");
```

This method of coding is called Object Oriented Programming. There's a thousand and one mistakes here, but it would work.

```
class MyLibrary {
    public Map<Integer, String> boombom;

    public void myLibrary() {
        boombom = new HashMap();
    }

    public void printElements() {
        System.out.println(boombom);
    }

    public void addElements1(int i, String s) {
        boombom.put(i, s);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to have `boombom` as an instance field, while there are only static methods which receive a parameter `boombom`, or alternatively, the methods must be made non-static, and the parameter `boombom` removed from the methods.

Comment: Correct, an oversight on my part. It should follow oop principles more accurately like so.